# Using a service to update the focused elements ng-class on ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to make my service be able to handle any input field. At the moment I am manually writing everything and it's starting to amount to a lot of manual work. Is there a way to send the element object when the elements ng-change property is invoked? I can then change the elements ng-class as a result of that.

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="email" data-ng-model="email" data-ng-change="changeEmail()" placeholder="your email here" data-ng-class="emailFormControlColor">
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.changeEmail = function () {
    if ($checkInput.checkEmail($scope.email)) {
        // email input is good
        $scope.emailFormControlColor = 'form-control-success'; // change from error to success
    } else {
        // email input is bad
        if ($scope.emailFormControlColor === 'form-control-success') 
            $scope.emailFormControlColor = 'form-control-error'; // change from success to error
    }
};
```

The service (this is included in the controller arguments ofc.):

```
.service('checkInput', ['$controller', '$window', '$location', function ($controller, $window, $location) {
    return {
        checkEmail: function (email) {
            // <--- I would like to update the ng-class of the focused element here! This would result in me not manually having to write code for each input!
            var regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
            return regex.test(email);
        }
    };
}])
```

The code above is how i have it now. As you can see I'm manually changing the $scope.emailFormControlColor.

Imagine I have three input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="email1" data-ng-model="email1" data-ng-change="changeEmail()" placeholder="your email here" data-ng-class="emailFormControlColor1">
<input type="text" id="email2" data-ng-model="email2" data-ng-change="changeEmail()" placeholder="your email here" data-ng-class="emailFormControlColor2">
<input type="text" id="email3" data-ng-model="email3" data-ng-change="changeEmail()" placeholder="your email here" data-ng-class="emailFormControlColor3">
```

How could I write my service so that I do not have the write the following manually:

```
$scope.emailFormControlColor1 = 'form-control-success';
$scope.emailFormControlColor2 = 'form-control-success';
$scope.emailFormControlColor3 = 'form-control-success';
```

I hope my question is clear, otherwise say and I'll update it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Sunil D. pointed me basically to the answer the code is incorrect. Down below is the code that makes it work. http://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/MyoZNB

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input ng-model="name" name="name">
    <input ng-model="email" name="email" check-email>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: silver;
}
.input-invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
.input-valid {
  border-color: lime;
}
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "";
  $scope.email = "";
}]);
app.directive('checkEmail', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.checkEmail = function(modelVal, viewVal) {
        var regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
        var isValid = regex.test(viewVal);
        el.toggleClass('input-valid', isValid);
        el.toggleClass('input-invalid', !isValid);
        return isValid;
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using a directive to solve this problem is more desirable. For one, it's considered an anti-pattern to modify the DOM in a controller or a service.

The other reason is that when you use a directive, you will be provided the DOM element that the directive was used on. Here's some untested code that you might use as a starting point:

```
myModule.directive('checkEmail', function() {
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {
    // require that ng-model is used on this element, so you can hook
    // into the Angular validator pipeline ... 
    ngModelController.validators.checkEmail = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
      // now return true or false if viewValue is considered valid
      var regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
      var isValid = regex.test(viewValue);
      // but you also have an opportunity to do your DOM manipulation
      element.toggleClass('form-control-success', isValid);
      element.toggleClass('form-control-error', !isValid);
      return isValid;
    });
  }
});
```

Instead of applying the CSS class as above, you could just use Angular's built in validation system. Your directive code is the same as above, except you don't apply any CSS classes in the directive. When the validation code in the directive returns `false`, Angular will make the field invalid ... and you can use this fact to apply the CSS in your HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input ng-model="whatever"
         name="email" 
         check-email
         ng-class="{'form-control-success': myForm.email.$valid, 'form-control-error': myForm.email.$invalid}">
</form>
```

The above applies the CSS anytime the field is invalid, but you can also apply it when a specific validation error occurs, in this cased we named the validator "checkEmail", so this also would work:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input ng-model="whatever"
         name="email" 
         check-email
         ng-class="{'form-control-success': !myForm.email.$error.checkEmail, 'form-control-error': myForm.email.$error.checkEmail}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an object that contains all of the information you need for each email. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="email0" data-ng-model="emails[0].value" data-ng-change="changeEmail(emails[0])" placeholder="your email here" data-ng-class="emails[0].class">
<input type="text" id="email1" data-ng-model="emails[1].value" data-ng-change="changeEmail(emails[1])" placeholder="your email here" data-ng-class="emails[1].class">
<input type="text" id="email2" data-ng-model="emails[2].value" data-ng-change="changeEmail(emails[2])" placeholder="your email here" data-ng-class="emails[2].class">
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.emails = [
    { value: '', class: '' },
    { value: '', class: '' },
    { value: '', class: '' },
];

$scope.changeEmail = function (email) {
    if ($checkInput.checkEmail(email)) {
        // email input is good
        email.class = 'form-control-success'; // change from error to success
    } else {
        // email input is bad
        if (email.class === 'form-control-success') {
            email.class = 'form-control-error'; // change from success to error
        }
    }
};
```

If appropriate, you could use something like `ng-repeat` to avoid copy/paste in the HTML.